# Python sqlalchemy dynamic relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to do something with Sqlalchemy, or if I'm thinking about it the wrong way. As an example, say I have two (these are just examples) classes:

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    addresses = relationship('Address')

class Address(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    if = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = Column(String)
    home = Column(Boolean)
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customer.id'))
```

And later I want to perform a query that gets the customer and just their home address. Is it possible to do that with something like this:

```
db.session.query(Customer).join(Address, Address.home == True)
```

Would the above further refine/restrict the join so the results would only get the home address?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt if a query construct is what you want, try printing it:

```
In [29]: db.session.query(Customer).join(Address, Address.home == True)
Out[29]: <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query at 0x7f14fa651e80>

In [30]: print(_)
SELECT customer.id AS customer_id, customer.name AS customer_name 
FROM customer JOIN address ON address.home = true
```

It is clear that this is not what you want. Every customer is joined with every address that is a home address. Due to how entities are handled this might not be obvious at first. The duplicate rows per customer are ignored and you get a result of distinct Customer entities, even though the underlying query was wrong. The query also effectively just ignores the joined Addresses when forming results.

The easiest solution would be to just query for customer and address tuples with required criteria:

```
db.session.query(Customer, Address).\
    join(Address).\
    filter(Address.home)
```

You could also do something like this

```
db.session.query(Customer).\
    join(Address, (Customer.id == Address.customer_id) & Address.home).\
    options(contains_eager(Customer.addresses))
```

but I'd highly recommend against it. You'd be lying to yourself about what the relationship collection contains and that might backfire at some point. Instead you should add a new one to one relationship to Customer with the [custom join condition](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions):

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    ...
    home_address = relationship(
        'Address', uselist=False,
        primaryjoin='and_(Customer.id == Address.customer_id, Address.home)')
```

and then you could use a joined eager load

```
db.session.query(Customer).options(joinedload(Customer.home_address))
```

Comment: @writes-on I'll address your comment that you proposed as an edit here: "This is in a function call, where home_only is a parameter of that function, so I can get all customer addresses or just the home one. Can you explain what you're reluctance to this is (since it's close to your example)?" – I'd be reluctant to implement such a dual-role for the relationship simply because it might come back to haunt you, though it might seem unlikely now. In the future the objects from that function call might end up somewhere where you or someone else would expect the collection to hold all the addresses

Comment: ... and since there's a cleaner approach to handling such a "home" relationship with a separate one to one relationship, there's little gained in adding complexity to the system by creating such a special case where the collection of addresses might hold all addresses or just the home. But as always, ymmv, and if the solution works for you, who am I to argue.

Comment: Thanks again llja, so far this is working for me. The model definition with the simple priaryjoin gets me a customer with all addresses. But, if I modify the query at run time to add the filter for home, I get a customer with just the one (home) address. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's entirely possible, though you would probably want code like:

```
# if you know the customer's database id...
# get the first address in the database for the given id that says it's for home
home_address = db.session.query(Address).filter_by(customer_id=customer_id_here, home=True).first()
```

Instead of having a boolean for home, you might try a 'type' column instead, using an enum. This would let you easily pick an address for places like work, rather than just a binary choice of "either this address is for home or not".

Update: You might also consider using the back_populates keyword argument with the relationship call, so if you have an address instance (called a), you can get the customer it's for with something like a.customer (which is the instance of the Customer class this address is associated with).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have been clearer about my question, the two classes are just examples I'm using to illustrate the problem. The example classes model a one-2-many relationship, with ForeignKey designating the join. If it do a simple query to get a customer, the addresses relationship collection contains all the addresses for that customer as well. But what I want is to override, or add to, the join criteria so I can query to get a customer, but the relationship collection only has one element, the home address.